# Detecting topology change of tubular neighbourhoods via smoothness of volume function

Tags: smooth-manifolds, manifolds, analytic-geometry

Let $M$ be an embedded closed manifold in $\mathbb R^n$, define $M_r=\{x\in\mathbb R^n:d(x,M)<r\}$.

Define $r\in\mathcal S_M$ iff $M_r\subset M_{r+\epsilon}$ is not a homotopy equivalence for all sufficiently small $\epsilon$, i.e. for all $\delta>0$, there exists a $\delta>\epsilon>0$ such that $M_r\subset M_{r+\epsilon}$ is not a homotopy equivalence.

Define $V(r)=\text{Vol}(M_r)$. Note that whenever $M_r$ is a manifold, $V(r)$ is smooth (in fact a polynomial in $(r,r+\epsilon)$ due to Weyl's tube formula.

## Detecting smoothness via the volume function

**Conjecture 1**: $V$ is not smooth at $r$ for any $r\in\mathcal S_M$.

The intuition behind this is that $r\in\mathcal S_M$ iff $M_{r+\epsilon}$ 'fills in holes' or 'creates new holes'. For instance, when $M=S^{n-1}$, the volume function isn't smooth at $1$. Similarly when new holes are created, the rate of growth of the volume function suddenly changes.

We know that $\mathcal S_M\leq\text{diam}(M)$, and if $M$ is smooth, $\mathcal S_M$ is bounded from below due to the tubular neighbourhood theorem.

A friend of mine has also found the following counterexample for the converse statement, i.e. the volume can fail to be smooth even though the topology remains unchanged:
[image: picture of counterexample, a "well" shape]
This is because the perimeter is not even continuous when the $r$-neighbourhood of the two vertical lines intersect (the manifold can be made close by a sufficiently big arc at the top). However, as such examples require the manifold to "have parallel lines/surfaces" for the topology to remain unchanged while the perimeter is not continuous, I suspect that the following may be true:

**Conjecture 1.1**: If $M$ is analytic, then the statements are equivalent, i.e. $V$ is not smooth at $r$ iff $r\in\mathcal S_M$

## Finiteness of $\mathcal S_M$

The motivation for the conjecture above came in my attempt to prove the finiteness of $\mathcal S_M$. Unfortunately, even when $M$ is smooth, $\mathcal S_M$ may still be infinite, as shown by the following example:

Let $N$ be the graph of the following smooth function on $[-1,3]$:
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{\frac1{(x-1)^2-1}}\sin^2\left(\frac1x\right)&x\in(0,2)\\0&x\notin(0,2)\end{cases}$$
Flip another copy of $N$ and translate it down by $-1$, then connect the two pieces of $N$ with something smooth like an arc, the resulting manifold has infinite $\mathcal S_M$ as $M_{\frac12+\epsilon}$ can have arbitrarily many of holes as we decrease $\epsilon$. The manifold $M$ looks like this:
[image: image of M]
(I used the graph $3f$ to make it look a bit nicer).

The reason is that $\left\{\left(x,-\frac12\right)\in\mathbb R^2:d\left(\left(x,-\frac12\right),M\right)\leq\frac12\right\}\cong f^{-1}(0)$, which has infinitely many connected components, but $M_{\frac12+\epsilon}\cap\left\{y=-\frac12\right\}$ has finitely many components only for any $\epsilon$, and the number of components increase as we decrease $\epsilon$.

This construction is possible precisely because any closed set can be written as the zero set of a smooth nonnegative function. However if we replace smooth with analytic, the zero set of any nonconstant analytic function is finite in a compact region, and such a construction fails. Hence,

**Conjecture 2**: $\mathcal S_M$ is finite for $M$ analytic.

My idea to prove this is as follows:

Show that $r\in\mathcal S_M$ iff there exists some $x\in\mathbb R^n$ such that $\partial B_r(x)$ is tangent to $M$ at $>1$ points. Then suppose that $S_M$ is infinite, take any accumulation points obtain those `points of tangency' from the previous sentence. From these points, construct an analytic function with countably many zeros in a compact domain, obtaining a contradiction. Unfortunately, I am not able to fully formalize this sketch.

Perhaps another possible route to prove the second conjecture would be to show that the volume function is not smooth at finitely many points but I'm not sure what can be used to prove this (something resembling Morse theory perhaps?).

Comment: Maybe the works of J. Rataj and S. Winter https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.07429 could prove interesting for what you're looking at. I can't pretend to have fully read their work, but it seems to me that they achieved some results regarding some of the questions that you raise.

Comment: @LoïcTeyssier oh wow thanks for the reference! looks like they have some pretty powerful results there I'll check it out and see if similar ideas can be implemented in the smooth/analytic manifold cases!

Comment: They're mainly interested in tubular neighborhoods of general compact sets, not anything close to regular manifolds. If it suits your needs, even partially, I'll post an answer with the ref.